# Multiplication in Laravel controller not displaying in view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to multiply the total dollar amount of cart items by a sales tax amount and have that displayed in my view. It seems to be working, or at least I get no errors, but I get no tax displayed in my view.

In my payment controller I have this

```
public function showPayment() {
    $cart = Session::get('cart');
    $payment_info = Session::get('payment_info');


    if($payment_info['status'] == 'on_hold') {
        $sales_tax = $cart->totalPrice * .085;
        return view('cart.payments', ['payment_info' => $payment_info], ['cartItems' => $cart]);
        $sales_tax = $cartItems->totalPrice * .085;

    }else{
        return redirect()->route("home");
    }
}
```

And in my view I have this

```
<li class="payment__item">Taxes: <span>{{ $sales_tax }} </span>
                    </li>
```

All my other data is working properly, just not the sales tax.

Comment: Your example is confusing.
You are passing a `$cartItems` variable to the view and calling a `$cart_item` variable. Inside this item you have a `data` attribute and inside `data` a `sales_tax` attribute. You are defining `$sales_taxes` variable after the view is returned and doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Bahaedin was implying is that you need to specifically define the sales tax variable if you want to use it as it is in the view. And, since it's bad practice to do logic/calculations in blade, here is one approach that would solve your issue.

```
 if($payment_info['status'] == 'on_hold') {
    $sales_tax = $cart->totalPrice * .085; //move this before the return statement && cart seems to be an object. 
    return view('cart.payments', ['payment_info' => $payment_info, 'cartItems' => $cart, 'sales_tax' => $sales_tax]); //one array, include $sales_tax as a variable.
```

And in your blade

```
<li class="payment__item">Taxes: <span>{{ $sales_tax }} </span>
</li>
```

Also, note that if you are sending `$cartItem` variable into the view, then you would need to reference it using `$cartItem` not `$cart_item` so `$cart_item['data']['sales_tax']` would not have worked even if you had sent sales_tax in a `$cartItem` array. If the way you did the multiplication is any hint, I would say $cart is an object, not an array.

Comment: Thanks, I understood what he meant. But that does not solve the issue. If I just try to echo out sales_tax I get the error that it is an undefined variable.

Comment: Can you share the `showPayment` function as it is now, with the changes I proposed?

Comment: I edited my original code to show it. I could not figure out how to format it here.

Comment: You are not sending the sales_tax variable here `return view('cart.payments', ['payment_info' => $payment_info], ['cartItems' => $cart]);` Check the return statement I proposed.  `return view('cart.payments', ['payment_info' => $payment_info, 'cartItems' => $cart, 'sales_tax' => $sales_tax]);`

Comment: Ahhhh, yes now I see that. I missed that last part there that you added. !00% makes sense now. Do you know how to truncate it after two decimal spaces?

Comment: use `number_format`; `number_format($sales_tax, "2", ".", ",")` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 0):

that's because you're returning the view before the multiplication  in the blade try this :

```
<li class="payment__item">Taxes: <span>{{ $cart_item->totalPrice * 0.85 }} 
</span>
</li>
```

Comment: I did that originally and it worked, but I need to be able to store that value and add it again to my total. I tried placing the multiplication before the return view in the controller and that does not work either. Any thoughts?

Comment: When you place the multiplication before the return view you should use the $cart not the $cartItems

Comment: I did try that as well. I still get the same result, which is that it returns no value.